# Validate other state form field in django

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, django-models

I keep getting form validation error when I try to validate a Django form such that, if 'other state'(State outside the united states) is selected, the user must type his state on another field (Other state field). If his state is a US state the other state field is not required.
Below is my code;

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    First_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Date_of_Birth = models.DateField()
    State_of_Origin = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATE_CHOICES)
    Other_State = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    Marita_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    Country = CountryField(default='US')
    Email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    Phone_Number = PhoneNumberField("Phone Number(+1..)", default='+1')
```

Form.py

```
class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Date_of_Birth = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget())
    #Other_State = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean_State_of_Origin(self):
        State_of_Origin = self.cleaned_data['State_of_Origin']
        return State_of_Origin

    def clean_Other_State(self):
        Other_State = self.cleaned_data['Other_State']
        if Other_State != 'Other':

            self.Other_State = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
        else:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Name is invalid")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def clean(self):
        Other_State = self.cleaned_data['Other_State']
        State_of_Origin = self.cleaned_data['State_of_Origin']
        if State_of_Origin == 'Other':
            if not Other_State:
               raise forms.ValidationError('Write Other State name because you selected other option from state of origin dropdown')
        return Other_State
```

Comment: Thanks NeErAj KuMaR, Your solution worked. I had to remove "return Other_State"  from your code as I was getting 'str' object has no attribute 'get' error.

Answer (score 0):

When validation fields against each other you need to use the clean method. Something like this:

```
class RegForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Date_of_Birth = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget())
    Other_State = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)

    class Meta():
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def clean(self):
        Other_State = self.cleaned_data['Other_State']
        if Other_State != 'Other':
            self.add_error('Other_State', "Name is invalid")
```

Something like that should get you started.

Also, try to use pep8 variable names. date_of_birth instead of Date_of_Birth